# intersection across date ranges from multiple rows in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Intersection of date ranges across rows in oracle.

I have a table which contains following records

| Item_no | item_type | active_from | active_to | rule_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10001 | SAR | 2020-01-01 | 2023-01-01 | rule1 |
| 10001 | SAR. | 2024-01-01 | 9999-12-31 | rule1 |
| 10001 | SAR | 2020-05-01 | 2021-06-01 | rule2 |
| 10001 | SAR | 2021-01-01 | 2021-02-01 | rule2 |

We need to find common dates between rule ids

Output will be

| Item_no | item_type | active_from | active_to |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10001 | SAR | 2020-05-01 | 2021-06-01 |

I tried with connect by level to generate dates and then take intersection, but it is running for long time due to 9999-12-31

Comment: Items in Rule 1 intersect with items in rule 2

Comment: Please clarify the rule you want to apply for selecting rows. Is it "Find all rule2 rows for which exists a rule1 row with the same item_no and a date range that completely covers the rule1 date range"? Or what else is the rule?

Comment: Yes.. We need to find all active_from and active_to dates which are common across rule id for particular item no, item_type..

Comment: Please don't say **yes** when you mean **no**. You **don't** want to select rule2 rows. In your sample data the date range just *happens* to be that from the rule2 row. You are **not** looking for rule2 ranges that fully cover the rule1 range. In the comment to the given answer, you are complaining that this answer doesn't deal with ranges with a single-day overlap. Again: Explain the rule you want to really apply in detail.

Comment: Can there be more rule_ids? How to deal with them then? Can there be multiple overlaps, e.g. rule1 = 2020-04-01 to 2020-09-01, rule2 = 2020-03-01 to 2020-05-01, rule2 = 2020-08-01 to 2020-10-01? How to handle this? Remember, being able to describe a task clearly and without any ambiguities is the base for writing the related query.

Comment: Table contains only 2 rule ids..rule1 and rule2..each of 2 rules contains any number of date ranges.requirement is, if any date that intersect between rule1 and rule2, then those active_from and active_ to needs to be captured.e.g. lets say if rule1 has active from Jan 1 2023 active to Feb1 2023..and rule 2 has active from Feb1 2023 to  Feb2 2023, then the common date here is only one, which is Feb1 2023.so my result active from is Feb 1 2023 and activeto is also Feb1 2023.Here we are trying to see each date between date ranges in rule1 that are matching with dates inside date ranges in rule2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Oracle 12, you can `UNPIVOT` the dates and then use analytic functions and `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` to process the result set row-by-row to find the consecutive rows where both rules are active:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT item_no,
         item_type,
         rule_id,
         dt,
         SUM(CASE rule_id WHEN 'rule1' THEN active END) OVER (
           PARTITION BY item_no, item_type ORDER BY dt, ACTIVE DESC
         ) AS rule1,
         SUM(CASE rule_id WHEN 'rule2' THEN active END) OVER (
           PARTITION BY item_no, item_type ORDER BY dt, ACTIVE DESC
         ) AS rule2
  FROM   table_name
         UNPIVOT (
           dt FOR active IN ( active_from AS 1, active_to AS -1 )
         )
)
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  PARTITION BY item_no, item_type
  ORDER BY dt, rule1 DESC, rule2 DESC
  MEASURES
    FIRST(dt) AS active_from,
    NEXT(dt) AS active_to
  PATTERN ( active_rules+ )
  DEFINE active_rules AS rule1 > 0 AND rule2 > 0
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (Item_no, item_type, active_from, active_to, rule_id) AS
SELECT 10001, 'SAR', DATE '2020-01-01', DATE '2023-01-01', 'rule1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10001, 'SAR', DATE '2024-01-01', DATE '9999-12-31', 'rule1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10001, 'SAR', DATE '2020-05-01', DATE '2021-06-01', 'rule2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10001, 'SAR', DATE '2021-01-01', DATE '2021-02-01', 'rule2' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ITEM_NO | ITEM_TYPE | ACTIVE_FROM | ACTIVE_TO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10001 | SAR | 2020-05-01 00:00:00 | 2021-06-01 00:00:00 |

and for:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (Item_no, item_type, active_from, active_to, rule_id) AS
SELECT 10001, 'SPR', DATE '2023-01-01', DATE '2023-01-31', 'rule1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10001, 'SPR', DATE '2023-01-31', DATE '2023-02-27', 'rule2' FROM DUAL;
```

The output is:

| ITEM_NO | ITEM_TYPE | ACTIVE_FROM | ACTIVE_TO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10001 | SPR | 2023-01-31 00:00:00 | 2023-01-31 00:00:00 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/avDdItmo)

Comment: If i have one row date range with overlap, it is not bringing intersect results..example.     Item_no item_type active_from active_to rule_id. 10001 SPR 2023-01-01 2023-01-31 rule1. 10001 SPR 2023-01-31 2023-02-27 rule2.   Here common date between rule1 and rule 2 is 2023-01-31. So output will be.  10001 SPR 2023-01-31 2023-01-31

Comment: @NarasimhanM Fixed. Needed to add to the `ORDER BY` clauses to process active before inactive.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for overlapping date ranges for the same item, but a different rule.

When do two date ranges A and B overlap? Answer: when the start(B) <= end(A) AND end(B) >= start(A). With this knowledge we can join. The overlapping range is just the greater start date until the lesser end date.

```
select
  a.item_no,
  a.item_type,
  greatest(a.active_from, b.active_from) as active_from,
  least(a.active_to, b.active_to) as active_to
from mytable a
join mytable b on b.item_no      =   a.item_no
              and b.item_type    =   a.item_type
              and b.rule         <>  a.rule
              and b.active_from  <=  a.active_to
              and b.active_to    >=  a.active_from;
```