# Oracle Date ranges that are present in parent rows but not in child rows

Tags: sql, oracle, date

Dates ranges that are found in rule1 but 'not in' rule2 E.g.,

| item_no | item_type | active_from | active_to | ruleid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10001 | SAR | 2022-01-01 | 2023-05-31 | rule1 |
| 10001 | SAR | 2023-07-01 | 2099-12-31 | rule1 |
| 10001 | SAR | 2023-01-01 | 9999-12-31 | rule2 |
| 10001 | SAR | 2020-12-01 | 2021-12-31 | rule2 |

In this case output will be the date ranges which are in rule1 but not in rule2 is.

```
10001 SAR 2022-01-01 2022-12-31
```

I have used connect by level which is taking more time to generate dates and compare them.. as date end is 9999-12-31.

Comment: Which rows are parents, and which rows are children? Add some more sample table data, and also _specify_ the expected result.

Comment: Parent rows are rows with rule id as rule1 and child rows are rule2..   Output is also given in the top for references..          
  10001 SAR 2022-01-01 2022-12-31.   It is like date ranges of rule1 minus date ranges of rule2.

Comment: Adding some more scenarios for result verifications. Item_no item_type active_from active_to rule_id.  10001 SAR 2022-01-01 2023-05-31 rule1.  10001 SAR 2023-04-01 2099-12-31 rule1.  10001 SAR 2023-01-01 9999-12-31 rule2.   10001 SAR 2020-12-01 2030-12-31 rule2.    Output of rule1 minus rule2 will be no results as all dates between rule1 and rule2 are present..so rule1 minus rule2 gives no result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adapting [my answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76385527/1509264), from Oracle 12, you can `UNPIVOT` the dates and then use analytic functions and `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` to process the result set row-by-row to find the consecutive rows where rule1 is active and rule2 is inactive:

```sql
SELECT item_no,
       item_type,
       active_from
       + CASE
         WHEN prev_rule2 > 0
         THEN INTERVAL '1' SECOND
         ELSE INTERVAL '0' SECOND
         END AS active_from,
       active_to
       - CASE
         WHEN next_rule2 > 0
         THEN INTERVAL '1' SECOND
         ELSE INTERVAL '0' SECOND
         END AS active_to
FROM   (
  SELECT item_no,
         item_type,
         rule_id,
         dt,
         COALESCE(
           SUM(CASE rule_id WHEN 'rule1' THEN active END) OVER (
             PARTITION BY item_no, item_type ORDER BY dt, ACTIVE DESC
           ),
           0
         ) AS rule1,
         COALESCE(
           SUM(CASE rule_id WHEN 'rule2' THEN active END) OVER (
             PARTITION BY item_no, item_type ORDER BY dt, ACTIVE DESC
           ),
           0
         ) AS rule2
  FROM   table_name
         UNPIVOT (
           dt FOR active IN ( active_from AS 1, active_to AS -1 )
         )
)
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  PARTITION BY item_no, item_type
  ORDER BY dt, rule1 DESC, rule2 DESC
  MEASURES
    FIRST(dt) AS active_from,
    PREV(rule1) AS prev_rule1,
    PREV(rule2) AS prev_rule2,
    NEXT(dt) AS active_to,
    NEXT(rule1) AS next_rule1,
    NEXT(rule2) AS next_rule2
  PATTERN ( active_rules+ )
  DEFINE active_rules AS rule1 > 0 AND rule2 = 0
)
```

Which, for the sample data from your previous question:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (Item_no, item_type, active_from, active_to, rule_id) AS
SELECT 10001, 'SAR', DATE '2020-01-01', DATE '2023-01-01', 'rule1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10001, 'SAR', DATE '2024-01-01', DATE '9999-12-31', 'rule1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10001, 'SAR', DATE '2020-05-01', DATE '2021-06-01', 'rule2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10001, 'SAR', DATE '2021-01-01', DATE '2021-02-01', 'rule2' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ITEM_NO | ITEM_TYPE | ACTIVE_FROM | ACTIVE_TO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10001 | SAR | 2020-01-01 00:00:00 | 2020-04-30 23:59:59 |
| 10001 | SAR | 2021-06-01 00:00:01 | 2023-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 10001 | SAR | 2024-01-01 00:00:00 | 9999-12-31 00:00:00 |

And, for the sample data in this question:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (Item_no, item_type, active_from, active_to, rule_id) AS
SELECT 10001, 'SAR', DATE '2022-01-01', DATE '2023-05-31', 'rule1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10001, 'SAR', DATE '2023-07-01', DATE '2099-12-31', 'rule1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10001, 'SAR', DATE '2023-01-01', DATE '9999-12-31', 'rule2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10001, 'SAR', DATE '2020-12-01', DATE '2021-12-31', 'rule2' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ITEM_NO | ITEM_TYPE | ACTIVE_FROM | ACTIVE_TO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10001 | SAR | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 | 2022-12-31 23:59:59 |

And, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (Item_no, item_type, active_from, active_to, rule_id) AS
SELECT 10001, 'SAR', DATE '2022-01-01', DATE '9999-12-31', 'rule1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10001, 'SAR', DATE '2022-01-01', DATE '2023-05-31', 'rule2' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ITEM_NO | ITEM_TYPE | ACTIVE_FROM | ACTIVE_TO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10001 | SAR | 2023-05-31 00:00:01 | 9999-12-31 00:00:00 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/PMkgolLO)

Comment: Thanks Sir for taking this question, please consider this test case, item_no item_type active_from active_to. 10001 2022-01-01 9999-12-31 rule1. 10001 2022-01-01 2023-05-31 rule2.  It is giving result as 10001 2023-05-31 9999-12-31.   Here 2023-05-31 is present in rule2 , so if we apply rule1 not in rule2 then 2023-05-31 should not come right? Expected output will be 10001 2023-06-01 9999-12-31.please help Sir

Comment: @NarasimhanM If you don't want overlaps then add to both the start and the end of the range. In Oracle, a `DATE` always has a time component so to get the non-overlapping range you can just add 1 second and then 2023-05-31 00:00:01 is outside of the range.

Comment: It worked Sir, i have added interval 1 Day to active from. iam able to get the result as expected.. in future, if i want to post questions specific to you, how to contact Sir. So that i can learn new things like this..

Comment: @NarasimhanM That is not possible. There are plenty of people who volunteer their time and you can ask questions of everyone.