# Implementing BODMAS expression evaluation in Oracle with split variable inputs and inner/outer brackets

Tags: oracle

Oracle implementation of bodmas expression based on given expression split into 2 variables.

Lets say, i have below expression

((Rule1 and Rule2 and Rule3) and (not (rule4))

I have a table containing following records

Item_no item_type active_from active_to rule id
10001 SAR 01-jan-2023 31-Jan-2023 rule1
10001 SAR 01-Feb-2023 28-Feb-2023 rule1
10001 SAR 01-Jan-2023 31-Dec-9999 rule2
10001 SAR 01-Feb-2023 28-Feb-2023 rule3
10001 SAR 01-Feb-2023 31-Dec-2023 rule3
10001 SAR 01-Jan-2023 31-Dec-2023 rule4

Here based on ruleid column, i need to implement bodmass type evaluation.

I.e.in the above expression,  first i need to evaluate all 'and' clause enclosed in brackets first and get the common validity periods( here 'and' denotes intersection of all active from and active to dates between rule1,rule2,rule3) and then based on this output , i need to use not in clause(minus) Rule4.

I am trying to implement evaluation on active from and active to clause in the above table based on ruleid column using bodmass dynamically. Whatever the expression i get, i need to evaluate the 'active from' and 'active to' based on bodmas type evaluations..please note, expression can be of any type.
(AND,OR,NoT)

What i tried is:

In this case, i need to pass rule1 and rule2 with 'AND' operator and get the result and make the result as R1. Now i need to combine this R1 with Rule3 with 'And' operator and get result as R2.once all rule1 and rule2 and rule3 is done, i need to evaluate R2 not with Rule4.

One more expression example: ((rule1 and rule2) or ( rule3 and rule4))

In this case,
Step1: rule1 and rule2 get result as R1
Step2: rule3 and rule4 get result R2
Step3: R1 or with R2 get final result.

How to achieve bodmas expression evaluation in this oracle. ( evaluate all inner bracket first as 2-2 rules and then evaluate outside brackets)?

Planned to create table and store inner brackets results first and then outer brackets for execution but got stuck if i have more than one rule combined with same operator inside brackets.as my function allows only 2 rule at a time

Comment: BODMAS is for numeric expressions. It is unclear what you are trying to achieve as `(Rule1 and Rule2 and Rule3) not (rule4))` is not valid in Boolean logic (you are missing an `and` before the `not`) and is not valid BODMAS. Please [edit] the question with a concrete example (rather than abstractly mentioning rules without ever defining them).

Comment: Updated my question Sir.Please could you help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adapting [my answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76392654/1509264) (which you can probably do yourself), then for `rule1 and rule2 and rule3 and not rule4` you can use:

```sql
SELECT item_no,
       item_type,
       active_from
       + CASE
         WHEN prev_rule4 > 0
         THEN INTERVAL '1' SECOND
         ELSE INTERVAL '0' SECOND
         END AS active_from,
       active_to
       - CASE
         WHEN next_rule4 > 0
         THEN INTERVAL '1' SECOND
         ELSE INTERVAL '0' SECOND
         END AS active_to
FROM   (
  SELECT item_no,
         item_type,
         rule_id,
         dt,
         COALESCE(
           SUM(CASE rule_id WHEN 'rule1' THEN active END) OVER (
             PARTITION BY item_no, item_type ORDER BY dt, ACTIVE DESC
           ),
           0
         ) AS rule1,
         COALESCE(
           SUM(CASE rule_id WHEN 'rule2' THEN active END) OVER (
             PARTITION BY item_no, item_type ORDER BY dt, ACTIVE DESC
           ),
           0
         ) AS rule2,
         COALESCE(
           SUM(CASE rule_id WHEN 'rule3' THEN active END) OVER (
             PARTITION BY item_no, item_type ORDER BY dt, ACTIVE DESC
           ),
           0
         ) AS rule3,
         COALESCE(
           SUM(CASE rule_id WHEN 'rule4' THEN active END) OVER (
             PARTITION BY item_no, item_type ORDER BY dt, ACTIVE DESC
           ),
           0
         ) AS rule4
  FROM   table_name
         UNPIVOT (
           dt FOR active IN ( active_from AS 1, active_to AS -1 )
         )
)
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  PARTITION BY item_no, item_type
  ORDER BY dt, rule1 DESC, rule2 DESC
  MEASURES
    FIRST(dt) AS active_from,
    PREV(rule4) AS prev_rule4,
    NEXT(dt) AS active_to,
    NEXT(rule4) AS next_rule4
  PATTERN ( active_rules+ )
  DEFINE active_rules AS rule1 > 0 AND rule2 > 0 AND rule3 > 0 AND rule4 = 0
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (Item_no, item_type, active_from, active_to, rule_id) AS
  SELECT 10001, 'SAR', DATE '2023-01-01', DATE '2023-01-31', 'rule1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 10001, 'SAR', DATE '2023-02-01', DATE '2023-02-28', 'rule1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 10001, 'SAR', DATE '2023-01-01', DATE '9999-12-31', 'rule2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 10001, 'SAR', DATE '2023-02-01', DATE '2023-02-28', 'rule3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 10001, 'SAR', DATE '2023-02-01', DATE '2023-12-31', 'rule3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 10001, 'SAR', DATE '2023-01-01', DATE '2023-02-03', 'rule4' FROM DUAL;
```

*Note: this is different to the sample data in the question as the sample in the question would return zero rows as the `rule4` row covers all `rule1` and `rule3` rows. The sample data was changed so that a row is returned.*

Outputs:

| ITEM_NO | ITEM_TYPE | ACTIVE_FROM | ACTIVE_TO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10001 | SAR | 2023-02-03 00:00:01 | 2023-02-28 00:00:00 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/3YF2G6Bf)

---

You can make similar changes to the answers to your previous questions to get the results for the other logic that you want to implement by changing the `DEFINE` clause of the `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` section.